# How to arrange network Scan for Canon MF237w on Windows Server OS

Tags: networking, windows-server, multi-function-printer

OS: Windows Server

MFP: Canon MF237w

I have MFP Canon MF237w and want to configure a network scan. The problem is that Windows Server 2012 is set up on PC. However, the official website indicates that Server OS is not supported for network scan. I have also learned that there is not opportunity to scan from MFP in share folder.

Could you provide alternative methods for arrangement of network scan on this device?